# How can I hang a heavy mirrored bathroom cabinet?

Tags: bathroom, drywall, plaster, studs

I purchased a bathroom cabinet today that is 1200 mm wide, by 750 mm tall, and 150 mm deep. When I brought it home, I discovered it weighed nearly 40 kg (88 pound) empty.

I was told that I could use 4 or 6, 10 gauge 65 mm plasterboard screws, by screwing them straight into the studs behind the plaster wall. If I have 2 studs I should just use 4 (2 in each), and if I can get it across 3 studs to use 6 screws.

Anyway, I am really worried that once it's filled with shampoos etc. that it could fall of the wall. Could you please give me some advice about the best fasteners to use. I think the studs are only 2x4, the house was built 10 years ago (house and land package by a big building company, so not top quality).

Answer (score 2):

That sure is a heavy cabinet.  I think you will be fine if you use at least a 2 or 2 1/2 inch #10 or larger pan head screw with a washer. Four screws/washers should be fine if you can only hit two studs, obviously, six screws/washers, two each in three studs would be better. Not sure of the metric conversion, but a #10 is about 5mm. I would not use anything smaller.